# MySQL/ PHP - Search on comma separated column

Tags: php, mysql, join, find-in-set

I have tables as following

```
staff
-----------------
id  name   operations
1   Mr X   51,52
2.  Ms Y   71,72,74
3   Ms Z   71,72,74,80,81,82
```

```
operations
---------------
id  name
51  BT
52  BP
71  CV
72  DX
74  EG
80  SR
81  FT
82  ZS
```

I would like to dynamically perform a search where in I could get multiple staff names matching the operations they can do.

The operations list will dynamically be generated as a comma list from another mysql query.

So, if I need to find all staff that can do operations `51, 52, 71, 72,74, 80,82` then the end result should look like this:

```
result
sid   sname    operations
1     Mr X     51,52
2,3   Mr Y, Z  71,72,74,80,82
```

The query should combine and give both staff names that can do the specified operations as single comma separated row wherever applicable.

I tried searching online with similar queries where people have used `FIND_IN_SET` but not ideal here as you can search only on one string at a time and since I get the operations list dynamically as one single comma separated list, it would be messy to loop through it to find out the number of times to write `FIND_IN_SET` plus it wouldn't combine matching staff names as comma separated list like above for staff id `2,3`.

I don't mind mixing a bit of PHP & MySQL to get the above final result if it can't all happen in a single query but any help OR pointers are appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the longest value for in `operations` column for table `staff`?

Comment: The first order of business must be to go back to the basics. Your database is not normalized. CSV is not a practical way to store data in a relational database. To be more blunt, it’s absolutely useless. What you need is a many-to-many relationship between staff and operations. this means creating a table that has a column for staff id and a column for operation id.  After that, it’s still a more complicated query than your average web page query, but it’s at least plausible. At this stage in the game, though, your question needs to be “how should the database schema be designed?”